# Получить bitmap из ImageView

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот загрузил в ImageView шейп круг с обводкой:

```
public static void customView(View v, int backgroundColor, int borderColor) {
    GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
    shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
    shape.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
    shape.setStroke(3, borderColor);
    v.setBackground(shape);
}


........

ImageView image_view = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.image_view);

customView(image_view,  Color.parseColor("#00ff00"),Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

Как мне из этого image_view получить Bitmap?

Вот этот код сразу вылетает:

```
Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) image_view.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Comment: Так Вы хотите получить background, foreground или то что видит юзер (скриншот вьюхи то есть)?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите получить изображение, выводимое пользователю из View, то можно сделать примерно так:

```
private Bitmap saveViewToBitmap(View v) {
        //создаем битмап, в который отрисуем вьюшку
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.width, v.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        //получаем от него Canvas, которым можно на нем рисовать
        Canvas c = Canvas(b)
        //говорим вьюшке нарисоваться на Canvas'е битмапа
        v.draw(c)
        return b
    }
```